# InstallShield 2009 Basic MSI: File Not Replaced After Upgrade with New Setups(1 file replaced)

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, reinstall, installshield-2009

**InstallShield 2009 Premier, Basic MSI project**

1. I have installed the setup, its installed.
2. I replaced a dll with a newer one and again prepared the setups(didn't change product code or any other code)
3. Now running the new setups, it asks for upgrade
4. I choose upgrade but after completing the setup I notice the dll is not replaced !!!

why and How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the file version of the newer dll to be a higher version than the previous dll? The new dll has to be versioned higher than the older one in order to be replaced.

Comment: **Updating the version is the right way to do it**. Another way is to set [**REINSTALLMODE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx) to **emus** instead (replace files with same version) of the normal **omus** (replace files with lower version only). Do not use amus which replaces any file. This could cause downgrade system files on older versions of Windows or trigger a file protection error on newer versions of Windows (files coming from merge modules etc...).